# Why does Python says that 'foo' is a local variable despite the fact that I have declared it global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was writing a small game in which you would guess a number between 0 and 100 in your mind and the computer will try to guess it. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import random
global foo
foo=input()
global k
k=random.randint(0,100)

def f():

  if foo.lower()=='too low':
    k=random.randint(k,100)
    foo=input('The number that I guessed is' + ' ' + str(k) +'. Please give your comment.')
    print(k)
f()
```

It throws an error saying:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable ‘foo’ referenced before assignment

Other posts on this site suggest to use `global`. I did and am still getting an error. Why is Python saying that `foo` is a local variable even when I have declared it global? And How do I get rid of this bug?

Comment: global has to be used inside the function

Comment: @PRMoureu , in my previous programs I used it outside the functions and it worked pretty well

Comment: @AaryanDewan then you were doing it wrong then, but it didn't matter because you never reassigned to it. If you're only reading from global scope, you don't have to declare it.

Comment: @AaryanDewan You just think it was working well or you were accidentally creating local variables inside your functions and luckily defined them before using them.

Comment: you may have declared global variables outside of the functions that used them [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/1248974), [How do you set a global variable in a function?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-set-a-global-variable-in-a-function.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Move `global foo` from the global scope to inside of the function like this:

```
import random
foo=input()
k=random.randint(0,100)

def f():
    global foo
    global k
    if foo.lower()=='too low':
        k=random.randint(k,100)
        foo=input('The number that I guessed is' + ' ' + str(k) +'. Please give your comment.')
        print(k)
```

Comment: I tried and it is giving the same error

Comment: About `foo` or about `k`? Because, well, you've got the same problem with `k`.

Comment: Just fixed `k` as well

Comment: Yes! it did work this time. Thanks. I needed to declare both of them global. Thank You

Comment: _"I needed to declare both of them global"_ - Yes, BUT inside the function, not at the global scope!